# hsqldb - How to replace a value in my Highscore (contains top 10) table

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have a table with 2 columns, Name and Score.
I and say it has 10 Names with Scores and i want to replace the row with the lowest score 
with a new name and score, if the new score is larger or equal to the lowest score in the table.

I managed to get the ResultSet of the highest value first but i do not get got to replace it with my new Name and Score  (in java).

```
String newName = "Test";
int score = 12345;
ResultSet result;
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Highscore ORDER BY Score DESC");
result.next();
if(result.getInt(2) <= score) {
    // enter code here
}
```

Comment: With "*replace the row*" do you mean you want to delete it from the database and insert a new one?

Comment: Yes i wanna find the lowest score in my table and delete that and replace with a new name and score, if my new score is larger or equal to the smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
            String newName = "Test";
            int score = 12345;
            int newScore = 54321;
            ResultSet result;
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Highscore ORDER BY Score ASC");// use DESC if u want to replace the highest value
            result.next(); 
            if(result.getInt(2) <= score)
            {
               PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE  Highscore  SET Name =? Score = ? WHERE Score = ?");
               preparedStatement.setString(1, newName);
               preparedStatement.setString(2, newScore);
               preparedStatement.setString(3, result.getInt(2));
               int updateCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Comment: Thx had to make a combination of your answer and the answer from cmd, but it worked out thx :D

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use following code to update lowest score record : 

String newName = "Test";
int score = 12345;
ResultSet result;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Highscore SET NAME = ?, SCORE = ? WHERE SCORE = (SELECT MIN(SCORE) FROM Highscore)");
ps.setString(1, newName);
ps.setInt(2, score);
int updatedCount = ps.executeUpdate();
if(updatedCount>0) 
System.out.println("Record Successfully updated");
```

Comment: Forgot to mention i wanted to replace the row with the lowest score with a new name and score, if the new score is larger or equal to the lowest score in the table.

Comment: But i solved it with a combination of urs and KaustubhSV,s answer. Thx